# Display specific virtual ethernet adapter status in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a simple application that I just want to display that status of a specific Virtual Ethernet Adapter after clicking a button (which also pulls some other info).

The adapter is used for a VPN and always starts with "PANGP"

[image: PANGP]

Currently have the following which obviously is not choosing the correct adapter but will show the network in general is up.

```
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces)
            {
                if (Interface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    if ((Interface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ppp) && (Interface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback))
                    {
                        IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = Interface.GetIPv4Statistics();
                        vpnStatus.Text = (Interface.Name + " " + Interface.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " " + Interface.Description);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vpnStatus.Text = ("Currently not detecting correct adapter but network is up.");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I don't need anything complex just want to show if that PANGP is disabled or enabled.

Comment: The loop is checking *all* adapters but only displays a status for the last one. Display the adapter status in a list, not a  TextBox. Or *filter* `interfaces` by name and display only the adapter you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this simply the case of filtering the list of network interfaces by the name you are looking for?

Something like this:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("PANGP")))
```

Which will return only network interfaces whose names start with `PANGP`.

Or alternatively if you don't wish to use Linq:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces)
{
    if (Interface.Name.StartsWith("PANGP"))
    {
        ...
```

#### Addressing the loop issues

As pointed out by @PanagiotisKanavos in the comments, there is also an issue with the loop you have created.  The output is being shown when `vpnStatus.Text` is set, but that will be updated for each element in the array with only the final element's values being retained in the `TextBox`.

The correct solution depends upon when there are multiple adapters that match the criteria or only ever a single one.

For a single one, simply select that and don't use a `foreach` loop:

```
NetworkInterface Interface = interfaces.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("PANGP")).FirstOrDefault();
if (Interface != null)
{
     // Display the appropriate text in your textbox
}
```

If there are multiple, the solution is dependent on what needs to be shown.  What *could* be done is to store each result on it's own line in a string and then set the `TextBox` to that value at the end:

```
string outputText = string.Empty;

foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("PANGP")))
{
    // Do existing logic and then instead of setting vpnStatus.Text, do this:
    outputText += Interface.Name + " " + Interface.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " " + Interface.Description + Environment.NewLine;
}

vpnStatus.Text = outputText;
```

#### .Description or .Name?

The property to search in may actually be `.Description` and not `.Name` as I have used above.  In this case, just modify the Linq (or the `if` statement for non-Linq) to use `x.Description.StartsWith("PANGP")` instead of `x.Name...`.

#### Note about variable names

I would politely suggest also that `Interface` is not an ideal name for your variable given the cross-over with `interface` (which is why it's presumably named with a capital letter).  Perhaps `networkInterface` would serve better and reduce the chance of confusion later?

Comment: The loop code will have to be fixed as well. The way the loop is written only the last adapter's stats will be displayed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for pointing that out.  I've modified the answer to also address the incorrect loop logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this has cleared some things up for me but now I getting my code all messed up :p Just to clarify in this situation there will always only be the PANGP adapter so I just need to box to say disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

With the above help, this ended up working for me:

```
            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = adapters.Where(x => x.Description.StartsWith("PANGP")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (networkInterface != null)
        {
            vpnStatus.Text = "Connected!";
        }
```